# CSS Dropdown Menu Issue with Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, menu

I'm running a Wordpress site, and having some trouble getting the dropdown menus in Chrome to show up. My CSS is here: http://pastebin.com/v291BmHP

and the menu code is here:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li class="current_page_item">
        <a href=".../" title="Home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2">
        <a href="..." title="About Us">About Us</a>
        <ul class='children'>
            <li class="page_item page-item-105">
                <a href="..." title="History">History</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It works fine in IE and Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: It's related to the hover "display:block" in the CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out display block in this rule:

```
#access ul li:hover ,
#access ul ul :hover  {
    color: #FFF; /* HOVER COLOR */
    display: block; /* DELETE */
    background-image: url('images/keating/nav_hover.jpg');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```